# Update database array without changing old values

Tags: php, laravel

So I am saving images to database as array:

```
$product = Product::query()->where('title', '=', $data['title'])->first();
if($request->has('product_images')) {
   foreach ($request->product_images as $productImage) {
          $file = $productImage;
          $slug = Str::slug($data['title']);
          $file->move(storage_path("/app/public/products/images/{$slug}/"), $file->getClientOriginalName());
          $images[] = ['img' => $file->getClientOriginalName()];
   }
   if($product) {
        product->update(['images' => $images]);
   }
}
```

But now when I upload new image it deletes existing array of images and saves new one to database for example I had two images inside array and I uploaded a new one it deleted those two old ones and saved only one new.

I want to make that if I upload new Image it would add to same array. How I should change this piece of code?

Comment: Use create method `product->create(['images' => $images]);`

Comment: `create` will be created a new record, but he wants to update an existing record without deleting  previous data

Comment: read the previous record save in variable and then push new images record in existing db array using `array_push`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new `$images` array from the uploaded files. If you save this array to an existing Product's `images` column, it will overwrite it, since you're never checking for existing. Try this code:

```php
$product = Product::query()->where('title', '=', $data['title'])->first();
$images = $product ? $product->images : [];
foreach ($request->product_images as $productImage) {
  $file = $productImage;
  $slug = Str::slug($data['title']);
  $file->move(storage_path("/app/public/products/images/{$slug}/"), $file->getClientOriginalName());
  $images[] = ['img' => $file->getClientOriginalName()];
}

if($product) {
  $product->update(['images' => $images]);
}
```

Since we're setting `$images` based off `$product->images`, when you add records, it's appending to an existing array, not a brand new array. Saving this to the database will not overwrite it.

There are definitely better ways to handle this, since saving arrays to a database isn't the best approach (hard to update/delete/etc), but this solves your immediate issue.